# is there a business object layer in apex

Tags: custom-object, design-patterns

We are building a custom force.com site application which uses custom objects with master detailed relationship. An example is a household which would have a collection of individuals and each individual would have a collection of incomes, expenses. Now all my objects are created with master detailed relationship. We want to create a ORM or business object layer like BO_Household class which would have a collection of individual bo's etc instead of directly using the standard apex custom object. Is there an object framework we can use for this which would map the master detailed relationships to collection of objects instead of us coding it manually? A framework like hibernate in java or entity framework would help. What do you guys use to create business objects?
Buyan

Comment: There is no automated tool/framework that I'm aware of, I've always just rolled my own BO wrappers. It's not really that much work unless you have to create dozens at a time. If you find (or create!) anything automated to assist in this I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 2):

As jkraybill mentions, you probably just need to roll your own. That way you can tweak it to your needs. I don't know of any framework that does this.

When building a BO wrapper, you need to be aware of how the additional code will effect governor limits. The wrapper is going to add some additional overhead to your application. If your app is small, you probably won't have governor limit concerns. If your app is large, or will be large, here are a couple of suggestions to take into consideration:

- Leverage caching in your methods that invoke queries so you don't accidentally re-query records when you don't need to. This way you avoid SOQL query limits. Lazy-load related records when possible.
- Try to keep the code tight. Being too verbose can lead to unnecessary scripts statements that can also lead to governor limit issues.
- Make sure you process your DML statements in bulk
- Use transient variables whenever possible to avoid view state limits in Visualforce.